# Minecraft won't install

Tags: java, minecraft

I tried to install minecraft on my computer, but it won't display on-screen.  I went to https://www.minecraft.net/download and downloaded the jar file. I put the launcher on the desktop and tried to run it.  It did not download minecraft. I can see the Java icon on the program bar, but it doesn't show on-screen.

**Note:** I have set the permissions to allow it to run as executable.

**Another note:** I have checked and it does create a .minecraft folder, but a lot of the minecraft files simply aren't there.

Comment: If you open up a terminal, execute your Minecraft launcher, do you see any error messages?

Comment: maybe this post is useful for you: [How to Play minecraft on Ubuntu ?](http://www.wikihow.com/Play-Minecraft-in-Ubuntu) I tested it on Ubuntu 13.04 and work perfectly

Comment: FirstStrike, thanks for the link to "How to Play minecraft on Ubuntu?".  That was really helpful, although not for the right Ubuntu version.  In response to BryceAtNetwork23, I have fixed the problem.  I am unable to recreate the problem at this time, so the terminal doesn't give any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.  This isn't a problem with Ubuntu.  It is a problem with Minecraft.  This happens in Windows also.  The latest launcher appears to be messed up.

**The Solution:** Provide your own ~/.minecraft folder.  The latest Minecraft launcher doesn't create a complete ~/.minecraft folder.  To fix it, you need to already have downloaded Minecraft before, and just copy the complete ~/.minecraft folder to replace the incomplete one.

Basically, the Minecraft launcher is, for some reason, unable to create a new ~/.minecraft folder (meaning that you have to provide your own).

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on if you are using OpenJDK or Oracle's Java package. For OpenJDK, the best solution is to reinstall. If you use Oracle's Java package, try uninstalling it and using OpenJDK.

Comment: I have had issues with this before, actually. I forgot to mention but I had troubles with running Minecraft for a long time. IF you want a last-ditch effort, install Wine, then download Java's .exe online installer and then Minecraft's Windows client. Again, this is only an if-all-else-fails idea, and problems may be experienced by this (occasional Wine crashes).

Comment: Thanks for the help, although I already use the OpenJDK Java 7 runtime.  I have solved the issue, and it wasn't a problem with the Java installation.